# Behavior binding boolean property not working

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here is My Entry Behavior:

```
public class EntryLengthValidatorBehavior : Behavior<Entry>
    {
        public int MaxLength { get; set; }
        public double MaxNumber { get; set; }

        public static readonly BindableProperty IsPercentProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IsPercent), typeof(bool), typeof(EntryLengthValidatorBehavior), false,defaultBindingMode:BindingMode.TwoWay, propertyChanged: (BindableObject bindable, object old_value, object new_value) =>
        {
            ((EntryLengthValidatorBehavior)bindable).UpdateIsPercent((bool)old_value, (bool)new_value);
        });

        public bool IsPercent
        {
            get
            {
                return (bool)GetValue(IsPercentProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(IsPercentProperty, value);
            }
        }

        private void UpdateIsPercent(bool old_value, bool new_value)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnAttachedTo(Entry bindable)
        {
            base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);
            bindable.TextChanged += OnEntryTextChanged;
        }

        protected override void OnDetachingFrom(Entry bindable)
        {
            base.OnDetachingFrom(bindable);
            bindable.TextChanged -= OnEntryTextChanged;
        }

        void OnEntryTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
              // my code 
        }
    }
```

Inside XAMl:
I used this behavior inside an entry

```
<local:BorderLessEntry Placeholder="{Binding PlaceholderText,Mode=TwoWay}" TextColor="Black" Style="{StaticResource SmallLabel}" PlaceholderColor="#d6d9db" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
                                           HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="20,0,20,0" x:Name="discountEntry" Text="{Binding Discount,Mode=TwoWay}" Keyboard="Numeric">
                     <local:BorderLessEntry.Behaviors>
            <local:EntryLengthValidatorBehavior MaxNumber="999999.99" MaxLength="9" IsPercent="{Binding IsPercent}"/>
            </local:BorderLessEntry.Behaviors>
                </local:BorderLessEntry>
```

from View Model just I am Binding the IsPercent value

```
private void ChangeDiscountType()
        {
            if (DiscountType == 1)
            {
                PlaceholderText = $"{GlobalVariables.currency}0.00";
                IsPercent = false;
            }
            else
            {
                PlaceholderText = $"0%";
                IsPercent = true;
            }
        }
```

here is my IsPecent Property inside viewmodel

```
bool _isPercent;
        public bool IsPercent
        {
            get
            {
                return _isPercent;
            }
            set
            {
                _isPercent = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsPercent");
            }
        }
```

all of property is working fine but "IsPercent" property value which I bind from my view model,and its not working

here IsPercent is a boolen property and when I set the Hardcoded value(ex: IsPercent="True") then its working

how to solve this?

Comment: Is this entry present inside some kind of a DataTemplate!?

Comment: no,its not inside data template

Comment: Adding an answer in a minute

Comment: Done you may take a look

Answer (score 1):

Your `UpdateIsPercent` is not triggered because you have to point out the behavior's binding context. Then its bindable property will be bound to the correct property of your view model:

```
<local:BorderLessEntry.Behaviors>
    <local:EntryLengthValidatorBehavior MaxNumber="999999.99" MaxLength="9" IsPercent="{Binding BindingContext.IsPercent, Source={x:Reference discountEntry}}"/>
</local:BorderLessEntry.Behaviors>
```

Moreover, I also recommend you to utilize attached property to do that:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/behaviors/creating#consuming-a-xamarinforms-behavior-with-a-style

Answer (score 0):

For people who do not want to use `Behaviors`, but instead want to do it in code-behind can do this instead.

### ViewModel

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public int MaxLength = 9;
    public double MaxNumber = 999999.99;

    private bool _isPercent;
    public bool IsPercent
    {
        get { return _isPercent; }
        set
        {
            if(_isPercent != value)
            {
                _isPercent = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private string _entryText;
    public string EntryText
    {
        get { return _entryText; }
        set
        {
            if (_entryText != value)
            {
                _entryText = value;
                CheckEntryTextFormat(_entryText);
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    private void CheckEntryTextFormat(string entryText)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(entryText))
        {
            if (entryText.All(char.IsDigit) && entryText.Length <= MaxLength && int.Parse(entryText) < MaxNumber)
            {
                IsPercent = true;
            }
            else
            {
                IsPercent = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Xaml

```
<Entry Text="{Binding EntryText}"/>
<Button x:Name="DoSomethingWithTheEntryText" IsEnabled="{Binding IsPercent}"/>
```

Now if you write something into the Entry, first `"CheckEntryTextformat"` is called.

The function then checks if the text entered is only numbers, not longer than 9, and not bigger than 999999.99.

If it is, the "IsPercent" property is set to true and because of `"OnPropertyChanged()"` the Button is notified and enabled dynamically.

Comment: I said that I am implementing this inside behavior not inside view model

Comment: Oh sorry, nevertheless this is one way to solve it. Sorry for misunderstanding you!

Answer (score 0):

In your View Model class add an IsPresent property:

```
 private bool _isPercent;
  public bool IsPercent
{
    get { return _isPercent; }
    set
    {
        if(_isPercent != value)
        {
            _isPercent = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("IsPercent");
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure to assign the above property, some value or else it will pick the default every time.

Your Xaml would look something like this:

```
<local:EntryLengthValidatorBehavior MaxNumber="999999.99" MaxLength="9" IsPercent="{Binding IsPercent}"/>
```

In your behaviour, you can use the `OnPropertyChanged` to keep a watch on changes in the `IsPresent` property

```
 protected override void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        if(propertyName= nameof(IsPercent)){}
    }
```

Or you can use the same as per your convenience.

### Update

After watching the code up close I realised that the IsPresent property in your Behavior is not a bindable property what you need to do is as follows in your behaviour:

```
  public static readonly BindableProperty IsPercentProperty =
      BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IsPercent), typeof(bool), typeof(EntryLengthValidatorBehavior), false);
    private bool _isPercent;
    public bool IsPercent
    {
        get { return _isPercent; }
        set
        {
            if (_isPercent != value)
            {
                _isPercent = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsPercent));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you add the relevant code maybe I am missing something, add the `ViewModel` and the `Xaml`

Comment: Edited my qustion,look this

Comment: Its because it is not a bindable property see I have updated my answer